# XDebug and VIM. Browsing array values

Tags: vim, xdebug

Is there any way to browse the data inside an array?

Currently I can only see `$data[0] = (array)` with no way knowing what's inside the array.

I can the values inside normal variables fine.

Is there a way to see inside the arrays? Maybe a command I'm not aware of?

Edit:

I found out I can use the command keys `,e` to evaluate an array or object.

After I type ,e an `/*{{{1*/ => eval:` prompt shows up then I can type `/*{{{1*/ => eval: $data[0]` to see the values.

Except I get it in the following output format:

```
/*{{{1*/ => eval: $data[0]

$command = 'eval';

EVAL_RESULT = (array) ;

EVAL_RESULT = (string) 'stringfromdata0-1' ;

EVAL_RESULT = (string) 'stringfromdata0-2' ;

EVAL_RESULT = (array) 'stringfromdata0-3' ;
```

This only does half of what I want it to do. Is there any way to output the keys of the array? It only shows me the values, but the keys are shown as "EVAL_RESULT" instead of the their perspective key names of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never got it the way I wanted it to work. Instead I found something way better.

Using [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim) I installed the VIM debugger for xdebug below:

https://github.com/joonty/vdebug

I'll post a screenshot whenever I get a chance.

Works like a charm though.

Answer (score 5):

Edit debugger.vim file (~/.vim/plugin/debugger.vim) and find a line similar to

```
let g:debuggerMaxDepth = 1
```

increase the depth varibale to a reasonable amount (5 should be enough)
save and restart vim.

Comment: Hi, did you know that you left an [unregistered account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/883959/aminalid). It still has an answer on it. You can request for the accounts to be merged if you want.

Comment: Thanks, yes, how do i do this?

Answer (score 4):

Also, you can wrap your expression in `var_export(<expr>, true)`, and it will show you the full object.

Comment: `print_r(<expr>, true)` also works for displaying the full object.

Comment: This is a good tip, to return the value instead of printing it, since Vim will display it!

Answer (score 0):

You can enter the vim command `,e` in a xdebug session.

From there you can evaluate any php line you want; for example

```
print_r($data);
```

and submit it with <kbd>Enter</kbd>

*Note: This will output to your php-cli stdout, or possibly output buffer if you are inside a `ob_start` block; Or if you are accessing from a browser, it may not output until the entire php request is completed. You may be able to flush a partial output buffer to a browser, but you'll have to Google that one for yourself.*

---

I Posted this as an answer even though its posted in the OP's question because I don't read the OP's question if I'm looking for an answer and I want to make sure people can find it! If the OP posts his answer as an answer and ping's me I'd be happy to delete this one.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about this. I forgot about this question since it never really worked the way I expected it to. However, I just posted an answer.